# Regex to get what is between XML tags

Tags: php, regex

With regexes, i would like to return everything that is between `<w:t ...>` and `</w:t>` in a content string

The regex I use is the following: `#(<w:t[^>]*>)([^<>]*)?</w:t>#`

Howewer, sometimes the content is cut at the beginning, so the content could start with `text</w:t>`

I would like to have a regex that matches:

- $1:''
- $2:'text'

and still continues to match the text surrounded by `<w:t>`

I now have two regexes (the other one is `#^()([^<]+)#`), but I would like to put them in juste one regex:

Example content:

```
 {#fuites}</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00E4576A"><w:rPr><w:bCs/></w:rPr><w:t>{</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="0066055D"><w:rPr><w:bCs/>
</w:rPr><w:t>type</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00E4576A">
<w:rPr><w:bCs/></w:rPr><w:t>}</w:t></w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00900433"><w:rPr><w:bCs/>
</w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve">
</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00900433">
<w:rPr><w:noProof/><w:lang w:eastAsia="fr-FR"/>
</w:rPr><w:drawing><wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" wp14:anchorId="1745F132" wp14:editId="7142C18F">
<wp:extent cx="225632" cy="179073"/><wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="3175" b="0"/>
<wp:docPr id="7" name="Image 7"/><wp:cNvGraphicFramePr><a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="1"/></wp:cNvGraphicFramePr><a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"><a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"><pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"><pic:nvPicPr><pic:cNvPr id="0" name=""/><pic:cNvPicPr/></pic:nvPicPr><pic:blipFill><a:blip r:embed="rId11"/><a:stretch><a:fillRect/></a:stretch></pic:blipFill><pic:spPr><a:xfrm><a:off x="0" y="0"/><a:ext cx="228029" cy="180975"/></a:xfrm><a:prstGeom prst="rect"><a:avLst/></a:prstGeom></pic:spPr></pic:pic></a:graphicData></a:graphic></wp:inline></w:drawing></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:b/><w:bCs/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> {Type}</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:b/><w:bCs/></w:rPr><w:tab/><w:t>{</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:bCs/></w:rPr><w:t>Description}</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR="00FF7A5E" w:rsidRPr="00FF7A5E" w:rsidRDefault="00FF7A5E" w:rsidP="00CA7135"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:bCs/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:bCs/></w:rPr><w:t>{/fuites}
```

Comment: I really like having the opportunity to use this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/57191

Comment: @cwallenpoole - was just a matter of time.

Comment: Those aren't HTML tags

Comment: (Not sarcastic in that. I find that post hilarious (tears-in-my-eyes funny), and I really like looking it up. The fact that it is *apt* is a double bonus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a second regex (and in fact you'll need more) because Regular Expressions are not a powerful enough tool to parse XML/HTML.  There is no way to construct one, or more, regular expressions that successfully do what you want.  Instead of doing this, I would suggest [PHP's XML Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) or some other XML-aware library.

Comment: problem is that is is not valid xml, as it is just part of a xml document

Comment: Can you provide an example of the XML you're working with?  XML parsers (can be) very lenient, like HTML parsers have to be, and may be able to get around this.  If the "XML" you have is so invalid as to be un-parseable, and you can't transform or wrap it in such a way as to make it valid, it's not actually XML at all, it's merely data that *looks like* XML, and in such a case you may be stuck - how can you hope to accurately parse unstructured data?

Comment: yes, they is some example content at the end of the question

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, the giant line spanning off into the distance is easy to skip.  I think you're pretty stuck, if that's really what you have to work with.  The first tag `</w:t>` closes a nonexistant `w:t`, already we've lost any sort of meaningful structure.  You say it's "part of a xml document" - can you start from the larger document and parse that?  You're in for a world of not-very-much-fun if you really want to work with the string you posted...